# Binding templates inside a page using knockout

Tags: knockout.js, templatebinding

I'm using knockout with and foreach for binding the template and properties.
Now for binding a new page i'm using something like this inside my main page:

```
<!-- ko template: {name: 'lib-dlp/views/share.htm' } --><!-- /ko -->
```

share.htm has:

```
<div> 
    <a href="" class="number_reviews"> (9 reviews)</a>
</div>
```

Now if i need to dynamically set number of reviews how should i do it. 
Also what's the best way to use it in knockout 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the template to your viewmodel. Try this:

```
<div> 
    <a href="" class="number_reviews"> (<span data-bind="text: reviewCount"></span> reviews)</a>
</div>
```

And make sure you expose an observable called reviewCount in your viewmodel.

Comment: Hey Juan, My Question was regarding including the template. <div data-bind="template: { name: share, data: course}"> Wanted to know here the name attribute here is it related to viewmodel or the view?